# I want to store the following line into a string array in C++. How can I do it?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to make a string array in C++ which holds 0000, 0001, 00002, 0003 and so on up to 9999. Is there any way to implement this  with loop. I do not want to take input manually. I want something like this.

```
for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
     str[i] = i;
```

Comment: I mean in c language or c++ language

Comment: `sprintf(str[i], "%04d", i)`

Comment: In C++ there are couple of ways to do this. You can either use stringstream of <sstream> or to_string method of <string> header. These are pretty plain ways and there is also other solutions such as using boost library etc.

Comment: Re "*I mean in c language or c++ language*", Please post different questions in different Questions. Since the body mentions C++, I'll remove the mentions of C. Feel free to post a C question separately.

Comment: A string is an set of cosecutive chars, integers are something completely different, so you have to convert the intdgers to strings, for C look at sprintf or itoa functions. Also you need to allocate memory for the string so that it can store the characters.

Comment: Many many thanks. Can you suggest me some resource where I can learn these staffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ideone.com/4kayTz

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> str(10000);
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::setfill('0');
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    ss << std::setw(4) << i;
    str[i] = ss.str();
    ss.str("");  // Reset/make empty the string stream.

    std::cout << str[i] << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Many many thanks. Can you suggest me some resource where I can learn this staff.

Comment: I don't know, just the practice helps to narrow search areas, plus reading manuals helps to find the best solution, plus Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.